# cordova implementation with ionic keycloak

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

i wanted to make a sso authentication with the help of keycloak so that i can validate but i am getting this error in this below code also i wanted to implement the deep link so that i can get the token and that token is essential how do i impelement the browser tab and deep link in this code so that i will get the token

this below is my app.module.ts

```
/* eslint-disable prefer-const */
import { ApplicationRef, DoBootstrap, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { CommonKeycloakService } from './services/keycloak/common-keycloak-service.service';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { InAppBrowser} from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';
const keycloakService = new KeycloakService();
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [CommonKeycloakService,
    {
      provide: KeycloakService,
      useValue: keycloakService
    }, { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },InAppBrowser]
  // bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {
  constructor() { }

  ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef) {
    let configKeyClock: any = {
      url: environment.keycloak.url,
      realm: environment.keycloak.realm,
      clientId: environment.keycloak.clientId,
    };
    keycloakService
      .init({
        config: configKeyClock,
        initOptions: {
          onLoad: 'check-sso',
          checkLoginIframe: false,
        },
        enableBearerInterceptor: true,
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('[ngDoBootstrap] bootstrap app');
        appRef.bootstrap(AppComponent);
      })
      .catch((error: any) =>
        console.error('[ngDoBootstrap] init Keycloak failed', error)
      );
  }
}
```

this below is app.component.ts

```
/* eslint-disable max-len */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/dot-notation */
/* eslint-disable prefer-const */
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';
import { PrimaryService } from './primary.service';
import { CommonKeycloakService } from './services/keycloak/common-keycloak-service.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private user: PrimaryService, private commonKeycloakService: CommonKeycloakService,
    public keycloak: CommonKeycloakService,private iab: InAppBrowser) {

  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    await this.getAuthInfo();
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('userDetails') == null) {
      this.login();
    }
  };

  login() {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('userDeatails') == null) {
      let IDP = 'samlNew';
      this.keycloak.login(IDP);
      const browser = this.iab.create('https://dbcluster.890enterprise.business/auth/realms/890Enterprise/protocol/openid-connect/auth', '_blank', 'location=yes');
    }
  }

  async getAuthInfo() {
    if (this.commonKeycloakService.isUserLoggedIn()) {
      this.commonKeycloakService.keycloakAngular
        .loadUserProfile()
        .then(async (profiles) => {
          sessionStorage.setItem('userDetails', JSON.stringify(profiles));
          // await this._httpService.generateJwt(profiles);
          let userInfo = sessionStorage.getItem('userDetails');
          let userInfo1 = JSON.parse(userInfo);
          let userName: string = userInfo1['firstName'];
          // this._httpService.userName.next(userName);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('Error in loading profile' + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    } else {
    }
  }
}
```

and below is my service file of keyclaock

```
/* eslint-disable max-len */
/* eslint-disable prefer-const */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/member-ordering */
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { InAppBrowser as brand} from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommonKeycloakService {
  activityStart: any;
  constructor(public keycloakAngular: KeycloakService,public iab: brand) {
    // this.redirectUri = environment.keycloak.url + '/realms/'
    //  + environment.keycloak.realm + '/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=' +
    //   environment.baseUrl + '/index.html';

    this.redirectUri = environment.keycloakRedirectBaseURl + '/index.html';
    this.activityStart = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

  }



  redirectUri: any;
  idpHint: string = environment.defaultTenant;
  tenantInfo: any;
  userInfo: any;
  loginId: any;
  private _tenantcontroller = `${environment.tenantUrl}`;

  isUserLoggedIn(): boolean {
    // return true;
    if (this.keycloakAngular.isLoggedIn()) {
      try {
        const userDetails = this.keycloakAngular.getUsername();
        return true;
      } catch (e) {
        return false;
      }

    } else {
      return false;
    }

  }

  public getRedirectURI(): string {
    return this.redirectUri;
  }

  public logout() {
    this.signoutApi();
  }

  private tInf() {
    let t: any = sessionStorage.getItem('tenantInfo');
    return t;
  }

  private uInf() {
    let u: any = sessionStorage.getItem('userDetails');
    return u;
  }

  public signoutApi() {
    this.keycloakAngular.logout(this.redirectUri);
    this.keycloakAngular.logout(environment.keycloakRedirectBaseURl + '/#/auth');
  }



  public login(id: any) {
    this.idpHint = id;
    this.keycloakAngular.login({ idpHint: this.idpHint });
  }

  public setTenantInfo(info: any) {

    sessionStorage.setItem('tenantInfo', JSON.stringify(info));
  }
  public getTenantInfo() {
    return JSON.parse(this.tInf());
  }
  public setLoginId(loginId: any) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('loginId', loginId);
  }


  public getLoginId() {
    let lgnID: any = sessionStorage.getItem('loginId');
    return JSON.parse(lgnID);
  }
  public setTenantProfileInfo(info: any) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('tenantProfileInfo', JSON.stringify(info));
  }
  public getuserDetails() {
    return JSON.parse(this.uInf());
  }

  public getUserDetailsObservable(): Observable<any> {
    const userDetail = new Observable(observer => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        observer.next(JSON.parse(this.uInf()));
      }, 2500);
    });
    return userDetail;
  }

  public getTenantProfileInfo1(): Observable<any> {
    let tPInfo: any = sessionStorage.getItem('tenantProfileInfo');
    const tenantProfileInfo = new Observable(observer => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        observer.next(JSON.parse(tPInfo));
      }, 1500);
    });
    return tenantProfileInfo;
  }

  public getTenantProfileInfo() {
    let tPInfo: any = sessionStorage.getItem('tenantProfileInfo');
    return JSON.parse(tPInfo);
  }
  public clearTenantInfo() {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('tenantInfo');
  }
  public getUserDetails() {
    if (this.isUserLoggedIn()) {
      return JSON.stringify(this.keycloakAngular.loadUserProfile());
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }

  public getToken() {
    return this.keycloakAngular.getToken();
  }

}
```

also this the error on emulator which i am getting [emulator image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pi70n.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to connect to localhost on an emulator you are trying to connect to a localhost that is run in that emulator. For most android emulators connecting to the localhost of the Computers the emulator runs on you need to replace "localhost" with "10.0.2.2" which forwards to the Computers localhost.

Comment: i tried changing localhost as well but the main thing is keycloak url its not stopping at that keycloack authentication url , its directly jumping from keycloak url to localhost and giving error

Comment: @irfanshaikh Can you run this app in android studio and see what error logcat throws?